# I need to access global (unmanaged) memory in c#

Tags: c#, memory, global

I am pretty new in c# and could need some help on a audio project.
My audio input buffers call a method when they are filled up. In the method I marshall this buffers to a local float[], pass this to a function, where some audio processing is done. After processing the function throws back the manipulated float[], which I pass by Marshall.copy to the audio aout buffer. it works but it is is pretty hard to get the audioprocessing done fast enough, to pass the result back to the method without ending in ugly glitches. If I enlarge the audio buffers it gets better but I get untolarable high latency in the signal chain.
One problem is the GC. My DSP Routine is doing some FFT and the methods frequently need allocate local variables. I think this is slowing down my process a lot.
So I need a way to allogate once (and re-access) a few pieces of umanaged memory, keep this mem fpr the entire runtime and just reference to it from the methods.

I found e.g:

```
IntPtr hglobal = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(8192);
Marshal.FreeHGlobal(hglobal);
```

SO what I tried is to define a global static class "Globasl" with static member and asigned that IntPtr to that.

```
Globals.mem1 = hglobal;
```

From within any nother method I can access this now by
e.g.

```
int[] f = new int[2];
            f[0] = 111;
            f[1] = 222;
Marshal.Copy(f, 0, Globals.mem1, 2);
```

Now comes my problem:
If I want to access this int[] from the example above in another method, how could I do this?

---

thank you for your fast help.
I was little unprecise seems, sorry

my audiodevice driver throws a buffer filled event which I catch, (in pseudocode since I dont have access to my home desktop right now). looks like:

```
void buffer (....)
    {
    byte[] buf = new byte[asiobuffersize];
    marshall.copy(asioinbuffers, 0, buf, asiobufferlenth);
    buf= manipulate(buf);
    marshall.copy(buf, 0, asiooutbuffer, asiobufferlenth);
    }
```

the manipulate function is doing some conversions from byte to float then some math (FFT) and backtransform to byte and looks like e.g.

```
private byte[] manipulate(byte[] buf, Complex[] filter)
     {
     float bu = convertTofloat(buf); //conversion from byte to audio float here
     Complex[] inbuf = new Complex[bu.Length];
     Complex[] midbuf = new Complex[bu.Length];
     Complex[] mid2buf = new Complex[bu.Length];
     Complex[] outbuf = new Complex[bu.Length];
     for ( n....)
     {
     inbuf[n]= bu[n];    //Copy to Complex
     }

     midbuf=FFT(inbuf);         //Doing FFT transform

     for (n....)
     {
     mid2buf[n]=midbuf[n]*filter[n];    //  Multiply with filter
     } 

     outbuf=iFFT(mid2buf)        //inverse iFFT transform

     byte bu = convertTobyte(float); //conversion from float back to audio byte

     return bu;
     }
```

here I expect my speed issue to be. So I thought the problem could be solved if the manipulating funktion could just "get" a fixed piece of unmanaged memory where (once pre-created) sits fixed all those those variables (Complex e.g.) and pre allocated menory, so that I must not create new ones each time the function is called. I first expected the reason for my glitches in wrong FFT or math but it happens in kind of "sharp" time distances of few seconds, so it is not connected to audio signal issues like clipping. I think the isseue happens, when the GC is doing some serious work and eats me exactly this few miliseconds missing to get the outbut buffer filled in time.
acceptable.

Comment: I don't see methods here. What does it mean to access something from another method?

Comment: not seeing much of your code i recommend encapsulating your processing wiht a `using` so the object is only valid for the time its beeing used and the garbagecollector doesnt need to take care of it

Comment: The main problem is that you're copying anything at all. Without seeing more of your code its hard to give you a proper solution. Simply allocating a static array on your static class should keep it alive for the life of the appdomain and shouldn't require "reallocation". That said, bulk copying your buffers around is going to cause you some performance issues in any high throughput environment. We'll need to see more code.

Comment: Short-living local POCO variables rarely introduce any significant performance impact. In fact, having a major amount of short-living variables is the scenario the GC is optimized towards. I would suggest not wasting time on this kind of optimization, but to look for a way to modify your code to avoid buffer copying instead.

Answer (score 0):

I really doubt the issues you are experiencing are induced by your managed buffer creation/copying.  Instead I think your problem is that you have your data capture logic coupled with your DSP logic. Usually, captured data resides in a circular buffer, where the data is rewritten after some period, so you should be fetching this data as soon as posible.
The problem is that you don't fetch the next available data block until after your DSP is done; you already know FFT operations are really CPU intensive! If you have a processing peak, you may not be able to retrieve data before it is rewritten by the capture driver.

One possibility to address your issue is try to **increase, if posible, the size and/or available amount of capture buffers**. This buys you more time before the captured data is rewritten. The other possibility, and is the one that I favor is **decoupling your processing stage from your capture stage**, in this way, if new data is available while you are busy performing your DSP computations, you can still grab it and buffer it almost as soon as it becomes available.  You become much more resilient to garbage collection induced pauses or computing peaks inside your `manipulate` method.

This would involve creating two threads:  the capture thread and the processing thread. You would also need an "Event" that signals the processing thread that new data is available, and a queue, that will serve as a dynamic, expandable buffer.

The capture thread would look something like this:

```
// the following are class members
AutoResetEvent _bufQueueEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
Queue<byte[]> _bufQueue = new Queue<byte[]>;
bool _keepCaptureThreadAlive;
Thread _captureThread;

void CaptureLoop() {
    while( _keepCaptureThreadAlive ) {

       byte[] asioinbuffers = WaitForBuffer();  
       byte[] buf = new byte[asiobuffers.Length]
       marshall.copy(asioinbuffers, 0, buf, asiobufferlenth);
       lock( _bufQueue ) {
          _bufQueue.Enqueue(buf);
       }
       _bufQueueEvent.Set();   // notify processing thread new data is available
    }
}

void StartCaptureThread() {
   _keepCaptureThreadAlive = true;
   _captureThread = new Thread(new(ThreadStart(CaptureLoop));
   _captureThread.Name = "CaptureThread";
   _captureThread.IsBackground = true;
   _captureThread.Start();
}

void StopCaptureThread() {
   _keepCaptureThreadAlive = false;
   _captureThread.Join();  // wait until the thread exits.
}
```

The processing thread would look something like this

```
// the following are class members
bool _keepProcessingThreadAlive;
Thread _processingThread;

void ProcessingLoop() {
   while( _keepProcessingThreadAlive ) {
      _bufQueueEvent.WaitOne();  // thread will sleep until fresh data is available
      if( !_keepProcessingThreadAlive ) {
         break;  // check if thread is being waken for termination.
      }   
      int queueCount;
      lock( _bufQueue ) {
        queueCount = _bufQueue.Count;
      }
      for( int i = 0; i < queueCount; i++ ) {
         byte[] buffIn;
         lock( _bufQueue ) {
            // only lock during dequeue operation, this way the capture thread Will
            // be able to enqueue fresh data even if we are still doing DSP processing
            buffIn = _bufQueue.Dequeue();
         }
         byte[] buffOut = manipulate(buffIn);  // you are safe if this stage takes more time than normal, you will still get the incoming data   
         // additional logic using manipulate() return value
         ...
      }
   }
}

void StartProcessingThread() {
  _keepProcessingThreadAlive = true;
  _processingThread = new Thread(new(ThreadStart(ProcessingLoop));
  _processingThread.Name = "ProcessingThread";
  _processingThread.IsBackground = true;
  _processingThread.Start();
}

void StopProcessingThread() {
   _keepProcessingThreadAlive = false;
   _bufQueueEvent.Set();  // wake up thread in case it is waiting for data
   _processingThread.Join();
}
```

At my job we also perform a lot of DSP and this pattern has really helped us with the kind of issues you are experiencing.